# Can My Macbook Pro Be Damaged From Power Surge

Tags: mac, power-supply, macbook, macbook-pro, gaming

so I have a MacBook pro 16inch i9 5500M 8GB and its pretty good for gaming, I usually get 200 fps in csgo on high settings and like 80-90 constant on GTA V. But since I live in Texas and we got hit with these surges and outages, after my electricity came back on I got on my MacBook and wanted to play some games but in gta I was dropping to 20 fps for a solid 5 seconds and then it would go back up to 60 (this was when I turned on VSYNC btw) and on CSGO, I was getting a solid 30-40 fps with all low settings on. What does this mean. Is my MacBook fired? Reinstall drivers? Thank you.

Comment: Depending on what kind of internet connection you have, it could be the connection "retraining" the line speed. This is common behaviour for DSL connections.See [router - What exactly triggers a "DSL Link Retrains" error on a dsl modem? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/341814/what-exactly-triggers-a-dsl-link-retrains-error-on-a-dsl-modem)

Comment: Yep, it's probably your network that's malfunctioning and not your computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's certainly possible for computers to be damage by power surges, it's unlikely that the symptoms would present as you describe.

While it's hard to guess what's specifically causing the issue you're seeing, I would suggest the following:

1. reboot (fully shutdown and restart the computer)
2. Ensure that your computer is plugged in and shows "Charging"
3. Try to disable "Automatic Graphics Switching" temporarily, to see if that helps the problem. Here is a link that describes how to do that: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202043

Answer (score 2):

Outside chances, the charging port was fried (check it sill charges), your Mac is compensating by running at a lower CPU clock speed, or the DGPU has reverted to the IGPU.
Run hardware tests, hold D at boot.

Connectivity should have *absolutely* nothing to do with fps. fps is entirely a CPU/GPU function.